# filter data while retrieving based on the current date time sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to retrieve data from `SQL Server` which are inserted some ten mins back and used the following query but it does not give the desired output and retries all the rows which are done upto date.

```
SELECT user_txn_details_id, 
       request_date 
FROM   user_txn_details 
WHERE  request_date <= Dateadd(minute, 10, Getdate()) 
       AND request_date <= Getdate() 
       AND pp_txn_status_id = 69
```

I really don't know what kind of mistake I make here. Please help me to correct my mistake.

**EDIT**

type of the field is 'datetime'

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substract 10 mins instead of adding like the code below.

```
SELECT user_txn_details_id,
       equest_date,
       DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, getdate()) as requestDateMinsAdded
FROM user_txn_details
WHERE request_date between DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, getdate()) and getdate()
      and pp_txn_status_id=69
```

or

```
SELECT user_txn_details_id,
       equest_date,
       DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, getdate()) as requestDateMinsAdded
FROM user_txn_details
WHERE request_date <= getdate()
      and pp_txn_status_id=69
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, still gives me the same result which was given by the query i gave.

Comment: what is the data type of "request_date"?

Comment: that should return the value, but are you sure it's already ten minutes is still within since you are using getdate() function which will return the current date.  Can you post the actual value of the record to be query (just a portion).

Comment: This the reason why I test the sql with minutes added.

Comment: when add 10 minutes then your making the datetime value 10 minutes ahead instead of 10 minutes ago.  did you made the 10 to -10